# swift handling NSData initialisation fails

Tags: swift, initialization, nsdata, xcode6

I have the following line:

```
let jsonResults = NSData(contentsOfURL: Fetcher.URLforLicenseInfo())
```

This compiles and executes fine but if the initialisation of NSData fails I get an exception later in the code. I have tried to add another line:

```
if jsonResults != nil { ///blah, blah...
```

but then the compiler complains `"Cannot invoke '!=' with an argument list type '(NSData, NilLiteralConvertible)"`

Shouldn't the compiler recognise NSData initialiser return type as an optional?

Comment: If the first line is changed to `let jsonResults:NSData! = NSData(contentsOfURL: ...` can check `if jsonResults != nil {...` and it works fine when NSData() fails. Why if NSData never returns nil!?

Comment: because `NSData()` is constructor, not method. It returns reference of current object

Comment: I can make the difference between method and constructor. In my previous comment when jsonResults == nil it means NSData() has returned nil...

Answer (score 3):

check the length of the data : `if(data.length > 0) ...`

Answer (score 2):

`NSData` initialiser will never return `nil` . On other hand when you write `jsonResults != nil` means that `jsonResults` is expected to be Optional but it's not.

The `if jsonResults != nil {}` condition makes no sense.

Instead you can check the number of bytes contained by the data object `jsonResults.length`

---

When to use `if != nil` statement?

Consider following example:

```
func toJson() -> NSData? {
  return nil // dummy
}

let jsonResults:NSData? = toJson()  // jsonResults must be optional

if jsonResults != nil{
    println(jsonResults!.length) // The number of bytes contained by the data object.
}
```

*Beware:* Since `jsonResults` is constant (aka `let`) its *read-only* variable and you can't change it in the future even if this value got `nil`

---

*Reference*

```
extension NSData {    
    // ...
    init(contentsOfURL url: NSURL)
    // ...
}
```